# Legends of Pie chart using Go Chart library

Tags: go, pie-chart, go-chart

I am using "https://github.com/wcharczuk/go-chart" library to create pie chart.

```
raw := `{"reaction_summary": {"ANGRY": 7,"HAHA": 40,"LIKE": 161,"LOVE": 56,"SAD": 26,"SHOCK": 6}}`

// Parse JSON
data := struct {
    ReactionSummary map[string]int `json:"reaction_summary"`
}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &data); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Populate a slice of chart values
var values []chart.Value
for l, v := range data.ReactionSummary {
    values = append(values, chart.Value{Label: l, Value: float64(v)})
}
// Initialize the chart
pie := chart.PieChart{
    Width:  512,
    Height: 512,
    Values: values,
}
```

I am having trouble in making legends for the graph. 
Could you please let me know about how to set legends for the graph?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpkyA.png)

Comment: A Legends of Pi chart would be pretty cool to see

Comment: raw := `{"reaction_summary": {"ANGRY": 7,"HAHA": 40,"LIKE": 161,"LOVE": 56,"SAD": 26,"SHOCK": 6}}`

// Parse JSON
data := struct {
    ReactionSummary map[string]int `json:"reaction_summary"`
}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &data); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Populate a slice of chart values
var values []chart.Value
for l, v := range data.ReactionSummary {
    values = append(values, chart.Value{Label: l, Value: float64(v)})
}
// Initialize the chart
pie := chart.PieChart{
    Width:  512,
    Height: 512,
    Values: values,
} 
how to set legends

Comment: @zaheerabbas can you please put the code on your question instead of putting it as comment? fyi, there is **edit** button underneath question

Comment: @xpare its edited. please review it